# Read Input from User (ActionScript 2.0)

Tags: user-interface, text, input, actionscript-2

I am just starting out using ActionScript 2. I am creating a game that has the appearance of the old text-based RPGs and I am having trouble finding how to get user input. Specifically, I will be asking for the player's name and certain answers to questions I will pose to them. I know how to do this in other languages, but the syntax is different enough that I am left stuck here. I am assuming ActionScript will create a command prompt style terminal if I do not specifically create a GUI for my program. If this assumption is correct, how do I read user input without creating input boxes? Basically, I want to keep the entire game within a terminal. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: What does your code look like now?

Comment: I only have a class set up with its attributes. There really isn't much to look at right now. This question is kind of a key step to continuing.